# Visual Studio Intellisense constantly popping up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using VB.NET in `Visual Studio 2019`. Type a single space character anywhere in the codebase and a popup displays a long list of options. You have to constantly click away or press <kbd>ESC</kbd>. This quickly gets annoying.

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic  > General > Auto list members` stops these unwelcome popups...but now "member of" functions are not listed at all! For example:

```
Dim test As String = "fred"
test.    ' Nothing is displayed when the dot is typed, but expected `Length`, etc
```

Is it possible to get Intellisense for "member of" only, but otherwise switched off and no other automatic listing (so nothing would be displayed when you are just typing away).

What a shambles to do so much with a single setting. If someone from Microsoft is reading this, check out how Borland's `Delphi 7` handled this...an IDE of speed and beauty.

Comment: Can't you just keep typing despite the popup?

Comment: *"You have to constantly click away or press ESC"*. No you don't. Intellisense doesn't stop you doing anything else so just do it.

Comment: Try to 'request a feature' in [developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion)

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Why would you think that popups, designed as they are to grab your attention, are not a distraction to others? When the popup is unwanted, obscures code you are looking as you type and so on, they you have to constantly click away or press ESC.

Comment: Because I've been using VS for 18 years and ReSharper for a reasonable portion of that and I wouldn't consider the number of times I've had to click away or press ESC to qualify as "constantly". Seems to me that if you would the you're probably trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Well I've been using VS for over 20 years, admittedly mostly VS6 and then VS2003, but also VS2005 and VS2013, and VS2019 has dramatically increased the number of popups and distractions compared with previous versions. But your 18 and my 20+ years in VS are irrelevant. This question is about trying to solve something that is a problem for me.

Comment: @dbasnett: Sometimes, but here's a concrete example where you cannot "just type". Say you wanted to enter "abc xyz" into the text. Ignore for the moment what `abc` represents...maybe you're typing a comment and forget the ', maybe you're going to define `abc` later, maybe you misremembered the type, whatever. If the Intellisense popup happens to have an option for `abcDisposableCollectionObject`, then you end up with `abcDisposableCollectionObject xyz`. You either need to click away (or press ESC) before auto-completion" or backtrack and delete the gumpff.

Answer (score 1):

(I realize this is an old question, but it still comes up in Google searches.)

Assuming you're coding in C++, I think the setting you're looking for is *"Text Editor/C/C++/Advanced/Intellisense/Disable Aggressive Member List"*

It's not perfect, but it gets most of the way there while leaving the member suggestions on after you type a dot.  (And the comprehensive suggestion list can still be invoked with ctrl-space.)

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion, though not applicable to `VB.NET` or `C#`. Microsoft have a decent IDE with Visual Studio 2019, but the constant popups are a UI failure (often annoying and generally unhelpful).

Comment: @AlainD, Oh.  Sorry.   You're right : That advice only works on C/C++.    Frustrating that VS has similar behaviors but completely different configuration options for different languages.    I stupidly assumed they'd all be similar.

Answer (score -4):

Very annoying that it distracts you that much. Im sorry to hear that.

Unfortunately, the final answer is that it cannot be solved, because microsoft would never consider an unpopular opinion.

The 'popup' is one of the most important features why people moved away from notepad in the first place. Every IDE will have it, and if they dont, they soon might. it is rarely unwelcomed.

With that in mind, microsoft didnt intend visual studio to be used without it.

Comment: So once a feature is added, it can never be improved or adjusted to fit the circumstances?  Wow. I hope you get all your stuff exactly right the first time.
What a strange attitude for a developer to have.